# Huge difference between real time and user time

Tags: c++, linux

I am running same C++ implementation in two different computation environment where the first one is Xeon 2.3 GHz with 48 Gb memory and the second one is Core2 Duo 2.53 GHz with 3 Gb memory. For the compilation, I have used g++ with similar options. I should note that first system is 64 bit Red Hat, second one is 32 bit Ubuntu. Additionally, g++ versions are different, in the first system version 4.1.2 is installed, in the second system version 4.6.1 is installed.

When I run the code, both systems return exactly same solution. For each system, time results are as follows.

**System-1:** 
real    0m19.623s
user    2m13.588s
sys     0m3.118s

**System-2:** 
real    0m11.229s
user    0m11.785s
sys     0m1.496s

I have 2 questions.

1. Why System-1 (better computation environment) runs this code inferior than System-2?
2. For System-1, the difference between the real time and the user time is considerable. Why such situation occurs?

Comment: maybe the computer is moving in speed of light.

Comment: Yes, code is single threaded.

Comment: What does the code do?  it's impossible to answer this for a 'general' C++ program because there is no such thing.

Comment: didnt some of the C++11 stuff get added between 4.1 and 4.6?  If rvalues were added, that could drastically decrease the times of poorly optimized code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I am using a shared library in my application. I realize that this shared library works multi-threaded in its default settings. I set it to single-threaded then it starts to work fine in both systems.

Answer (score 0):

why user time is large?

if you have 2 core, both running in user mode for 1 minute each, you get 2 user minute.

This hints your  code don't do well on multithread. Something like busy waiting on lock contention, or cache contention may be the cause.